# How to recreate compiled classes?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm having the following structure within a GWT project:

```
war/WEB-INF/classes
```

For cleanup, as I had some caching issues, I deleted the whole classes folder.
Now when I run the GWT project locally, I'm getting ClassNotFound Exceptions, as the classes folder is somehow not recreated.

Why do I have to probably retrigger the classes creation? And how could I do this? So far I never had to deal with those classes creation, it just worked automatically. Why does it fail now?

Comment: have you tried clean the project ??

Comment: create an empty classes folder, then clean project?

Comment: Tried this, but all folders beside the "client" folder gets deleted!

Comment: What do you see in your classes folder?

Comment: Only the *.class files from the `client` folder.

Comment: Is it a maven project or simple GPE project?

Comment: The project is mavenized. I use maven just to resolve dependencies. Compilation, deployment etc is all done using eclipse google plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it turned out to be a configuration issue:

```
Project properties > Java Build Path > Source > Default output folder
```